# How does "showpage()" work in this piece of code?

Tags: if-statement, lua

I have been learning Lua from http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html and they had this piece of code:

```
if line > MAXLINES then
  showpage()
  line = 0
end
```

I don't understand what "showpage()" does here. I don't know whether this is just an example of a function that had to be previously defined (and I don't know if you can actually do this with a function) or is it a library I don't know of.

Comment: That is just an example of the application of an if statement. That particular section is just discussing the structure of an if statement. You could replace `showpage()` with `print('The if statement was true!')` for a more interactive example

Comment: Thanks. I think that answers my question. I should've known better.

Comment: It is not a bad question most of the examples are complete snippets, i am actually surprised that that one doesn't have a `print` rather then `showpage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showpage` is not a standard Lua function. You can find any of Lua's built-in functions in the [Lua reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/).

If you don't find a function there it is user-defined. You'll learn how to define functions in chapter 5.

It is indeed necessary that `showpage` is defined befor you call it. Otherwise you will face an error message for calling a `nil` value.

You'll find that many code examples skip the definition of some variables.

```
 if a<0 then a = 0 end

 if a<b then return a else return b end

 if line > MAXLINES then
   showpage()
   line = 0
 end
```

In this example `a`, `b`, `showpage`, `line` and `MAXLINES` are all `nil`. All of this would cause errors as you're neither allowed to call nil values nor to compare nil values with numbers.

Not sure if the authors were lazy, wanted to reduce the page count or intended to make you to think about their code.